# Support for external CSS file from Apache FOP PDF Generation

Tags: java, css, pdf-generation, apache-fop, html-to-pdf

Does the apache FOP supports external CSS file for generating PDF from html document? I am specifying the css file path html file but styles are not applied on pdf report generated. Also I tried copy pasting the entire style content inside  tag in html document. Still generated report does not the style applied. Since I am the beginner for FOP, I would be really great if someone tells me What am I missing here?

Another fundamental question would be.. does the Apache FOP supports external css file?

Answer (score 1):

To use CSS with XSL FO you would need something that processes CSS into XSL FO. You can look at the link below which is not Apache FOP but uses RenderX XEP behind the scenes. It allows for XML and/or HTML with CSS internal and external, leveraging XSL FO technology to format content.

http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf